# java.sql.SQLException: enlist: caught Exception

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, websphere-7, sqlexception

In WAS7(websphere-7) --- trying to access two database using a XATransactionFunction. In one of them I am getting the error below. Both the database are under XATransactionFunction and database is XA enabled(According to our DBA). The code breaks when I try to access the prepared statement trying to run a select query.
Databse: SQL Server 2008, Driver : sqljdbc4.0
What Am I missing??

Please help.

Tried already : 
1. Enabled LPS in application ear files , reconfigured the application to accept the heuristic risk.

```
 String sql = createSelectSql(TABLE_WITH_SCHEMA_NAME, SINGLE_ROW_BY_VOUCHER_KEY_FIELD_NAMES);
    ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);


[6/13/14 12:07:00:503 MDT] 00000025 RegisteredRes E   WTRN0062E: An illegal attempt to use multiple resources that have only one-phase capability has occurred within a global transaction.
[6/13/14 12:07:00:614 MDT] 00000025 LocalTransact E   J2CA0030E: Method enlist caught com.ibm.ws.Transaction.IllegalResourceIn2PCTransactionException: Illegal attempt to enlist multiple 1PC XAResources
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:1788)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.enlistOnePhase(TranManagerSet.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.enlist(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:593)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.lazyEnlist(ConnectionManager.java:2231)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.lazyEnlist(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2519)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.beginTransactionIfNecessary(WSJdbcConnection.java:717)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2760)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2713)
    at ca.ab.gov.acs.cfm.voucher.VoucherHeader.findHeader(VoucherHeader.java:322)
```

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247192 Hope it helps!

Comment: It say . change from using a non-XA JDBC provider to an XA JDBC provider for one of the data sources that is non-XA.  I am already using SQL server Jdbc driver sqljdbc4.0 how can i make it XA???

Comment: Check this link and ensure your database is correctly set up - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2011/10/27/unable-to-do-remote-sql-stored-procedure-debugging-from-vs2010.aspx . What is your second resource? How you are getting datasources/connections?